# Display On-Screen (Virtual) Keyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to display/hide the On-Screen keyboard manually from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It was a design decision (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx#user-driven_invocation)) to give the end user control of the keyboard being invoked.  Therefore, the end user has to touch a text box (or the like) to invoke the virtual on-screen keyboard.

From that link:

> "The invocation model of the touch keyboard is designed to put the
>   user in control of the keyboard. Users indicate to the system that
>   they want to input text by tapping on an input control instead of
>   having an application make that decision on their behalf. This reduces
>   to zero the scenarios where the keyboard is invoked unexpectedly,
>   which can be a painful source of UI churn because the keyboard can
>   consume up to 50% of the screen and mar the application's user
>   experience. To enable user-driven invocation, we track the coordinates
>   of the last touch event and compare them to the location of the
>   bounding rectangle of the element that currently has focus. If the
>   point is contained within the bounding rectangle, the touch keyboard
>   is invoked.
>
> This means that applications cannot programmatically invoke the touch
>   keyboard via manipulation of focus."